# c++ count the number of occurrences of each word in string using an array?

Tags: c++, arrays, dictionary, count

I currently have a function that does what the question says(counts the number of occurrences of each word in string) However it uses map. This is for a university level task and we arent allowed to use maps for the count(something i didnt read haha)

```
void wordCount(std::string wordFile)
{

  std::map<std::string, int> M;

  std::string word = "";

  for (int i = 0; i < str.size(); i++)
  {

    if (str[i] == ' ')
    {

      if (M.find(word) == M.end())
      {
        M.insert(make_pair(word, 1));
        word = "";
      }

      else
      {
        M[word]++;
        word = "";
      }
    }

    else
      word += str[i];
  }

  if (M.find(word) == M.end())
    M.insert(make_pair(word, 1));

  else
    M[word]++;

  for (auto &it : M)
  {
    std::cout << it.first << ": Occurs "
              << it.second
              << std::endl;
  }
}
```

So my quesiton is, is there a way to do the above but using arrays and not map?

Comment: Sure, a map of word to count is just two arrays: search the array for the word, then take the index where it was found and use that index on the array of counts.

Comment: Note that your `map`-based solution is quite inefficient and needlessly complicated. It can be greatly simplified: `void wordCount(const std::string &wordFile) { std::map<std::string, int> M; std::istringstream iss(wordFile); std::string word; while (iss >> word) { M[word]++; } for (const auto &it : M) { std::cout << it.first << ": Occurs " << it.second << std::endl; } }`

Comment: `This is for a university level task and we arent allowed to use maps for the count`. I read this as `This is for a university level task and we arent allowed to use screwdrivers to loosen the screws`

Comment: Sample: https://onlinegdb.com/S1L1a-5mP

Answer (score 0):

A good solution since you are forbidden to use maps would simply be to use two vectors, one for the words and another for the number of occurrences of each word, with matching indexes.

When it comes down to it it works pretty much exactly like a map, but since you have that arbitrary restriction that would be the alternative.

To implement this, just replace `M` by the two vectors, let's call them `wordVector` and `countVector`. You can then insert the words like this to make sure the indexes match and the counts are good:

```
if (str[i] == ' ')
    {

      if (wordVector.find(word) == wordVector.end())
      {
        wordVector.insert(word);
        countVector.insert(1);
        word = "";
      }

      else
      {
        int index = wordVector.find(word)
        ++countVector[index];
        word = "";
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can be done, but also yes, you normally want to do it somewhat (okay, completely) differently.

I'd do it in phases:

1. break the input string up into words and create a vector of individual words

- and possibly do a bit of massaging, such as converting the all to lower case

2. Sort the vector of words
3. Starting from the first word in the list, count the number of following identical words

- And add the {word:count} result to your output

4. Repeat that starting from the first word that mismatched its predecessor
5. (for a bonus) sort the vector of {word:count} pairs by the count (probably in descending order), so you get a count like:

   ```
    the: 583
    a: 428
    an: 422
    // ...
    dioxide: 2
    arthurian: 1
   ```